# Group representation over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, invariant-subspace

The representation theory of finite groups over the fields $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ is clear. I am wondering what happens if we consider something similar over the ring $\mathbb{Z}$. To be more precise, let $G$ be a finite subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$, and we consider the action of $G$ on $\mathbb{Z}^n$.

- $\textbf{Question 1}$: How to check that there are no nontrivial $G$-invariant subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^n$?
- $\textbf{Question 2}$: Is it possible to describe $G$-invariant subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^n$?

Could you suggest a good reference dealing with such questions?

Comment: As first thought I would tensorise by $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ to return to the original case, then try to see if it fits. But I'm no expert on this subject. Have you tried looking at some examples ? since root systems deals with linear combination in $\mathbb{Z}$, it could be a way?

Comment: If $n>0$, then there will always be $G$-invariant proper subgroups (of the form $k\mathbb{Z}^{n}$). More generally, all irreducible finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-representations of $G$ are by the above $p$-torsion for some prime $p$, so such irreps are all restrictions (along the change-of-coefficients group ring map) of irreps of $G$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$.

Comment: (But there’s an important caveat here—not all finitely generated representations over $\mathbb{Z}$ are of finite length, so looking at the irreps no longer gives you as much of the whole picture.)

Comment: @Rafi Ok, so there is always an invariant subgroup, it's not good. But is there some analog to the direct sum decomposition into irreducibles? In other words, is there decomposition $\mathbb{Z}^n=H_1\oplus\ldots\oplus H_m$, where $H_i$ are $G$-invariant, and such a decomposition is minimal in some sense?